# How to create a VPN by using only SSH access?

Tags: vpn

Is it possible to create a VPN tunnel from a client computer if the only thing you have is the possibility to initiate a SSH connection to a machine that has access to the "intranet"?

I know how to do this for specific ports but I am looking for a solution that would work for all ports.

FYI, the server is running Debian and the client OS X 10.8

Comment: Who's security are you trying to bypass?

Answer (score 2):

SSH can have many ports forwarded, you aren't limited to one per session.

But if you really can't predict what ports you are going to want use. openvpn tunnelled through ssh.

http://www.niteoweb.com/blog/openvpn-over-ssh

Comment: The openvpn solution pre-supposes that openvpn is available on the remote system or can be installed (in which case, why bother with the ssh layer?). If openvpn is not an option then check if ppd is available - see also http://tldp.org/HOWTO/ppp-ssh/

Comment: He bothers with the ssh layer, because from his description of the problem it appears the only traffic he can route to the server is ssh. Debian includes openvpn 2.1.3-2+squeeze1 in the stable build. On Macos he can use one of the package managers to install openvpn or follow this even more step by step howto. http://blog.acmelab.org/2008/07/20/mac-os-x-openvpn-bridge-ssh-tunnel-vpn-goodness/